# Static nested class inside parameterized class

Tags: java

I was looking at the Java code implementing a binary search tree shown [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html) and I thought that it would be better if the inner class `Node` was in fact turned into a [static nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). However, adding the `static` keyword in front (I thought I could do this since the inner class does not in fact anywhere use the instance of the enclosing class -- the one I can access in the `Node` inner class as `BST.this` -- that is bound to it) resulted in multiple errors which were not extremely helpful.

As far as I'm aware, `java.util.LinkedList` and similar also used static nested classes to define the nodes stored inside and are also parameterized (and, of course, work without any problems). Anyone care to elaborate?

Thanks.

Comment: `I thought that it would be better if the inner class Node was in fact turned into a static nested class` -- Why?

Comment: Because I think that the inner class does not need to be "inner." It does not use the reference of the enclosing class that is bound to it to invoke any of the enclosing class' instance methods or access any instance members. Am I wrong in thinking so? I once read that it was a wise idea to always start off with a static nested class and see later if you need to "convert" it to an inner class.

Comment: `new Node<Key, Value>(key, val, 1)` (inside the enclosing class, otherwise `new EnclosingClass.StaticNestedClass(...)`)? Isn't that what [java.util.LinkedList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java) does? I began learning Java some 10 days ago, so I'm a bit lost, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make the inner class `static`, you'll lose the type parameters of the surrounding class. `Node` has no access to `Key` and `Value`, since it's no longer associated with a instance of `BST`. You can fix this by adding type parameters to `Node` too:

```
private class Node<NodeKey extends Comparable<NodeKey>, NodeValue> {
    private NodeKey key;           // sorted by key
    private NodeValue val;         // associated data
    private Node<NodeKey, NodeValue> left, right;  // left and right subtrees
    private int N;             // number of nodes in subtree

    public Node(NodeKey key, NodeValue val, int N) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
        this.N = N;
    }
}
```

And replacing every occurence of `Node` with `Node<Key, Value>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the parametrization and added `static` as I had originally, and everything worked well. I knew it had something to do with the type parameters!